# How to add method description in Swagger UI in WebAPI Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, restful-url, swashbuckle

I am using Swagger as my API tooling framework and it is working out great so far. I just came across this page https://petstore.swagger.io/

and saw how each method has a description. For example,

`POST: pet/` is described by `add a new Pet to the store`. I thought adding something like `[Description("Description text")]` should do it but it just does not. How can I achieve this?

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This is well documented in the project:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments

---

#### Include Descriptions from XML Comments

To enhance the generated docs with human-friendly descriptions, you can annotate controller actions and models with [Xml Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(v=vs.110).aspx) and configure Swashbuckle to incorporate those comments into the outputted Swagger JSON:

1 - Open the Properties dialog for your project, click the "Build" tab and ensure that "XML documentation file" is checked. This will produce a file containing all XML comments at build-time.

*At this point, any classes or methods that are NOT annotated with XML comments will trigger a build warning. To suppress this, enter the warning code "1591" into the "Suppress warnings" field in the properties dialog.*

2 - Configure Swashbuckle to incorporate the XML comments on file into the generated Swagger JSON:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
        new Info
        {
            Title = "My API - V1",
            Version = "v1"
        }
     );

     var filePath = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "MyApi.xml");
     c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
}
```

3 - Annotate your actions with summary, remarks and response tags:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves a specific product by unique id
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Awesomeness!</remarks>
/// <response code="200">Product created</response>
/// <response code="400">Product has missing/invalid values</response>
/// <response code="500">Oops! Can't create your product right now</response>
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Product), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IDictionary<string, string>), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public Product GetById(int id)
```

4 - You can also annotate types with summary and example tags:

```
public class Product
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the product
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>Men's basketball shoes</example>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Quantity left in stock
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>10</example>
    public int AvailableStock { get; set; }
}
```

5 - Rebuild your project to update the XML Comments file and navigate to the Swagger JSON endpoint. Note how the descriptions are mapped onto corresponding Swagger fields.

*NOTE: You can also provide Swagger Schema descriptions by annotating your API models and their properties with summary tags. If you have multiple XML comments files (e.g. separate libraries for controllers and models), you can invoke the IncludeXmlComments method multiple times and they will all be merged into the outputted Swagger JSON.*

---

Following the instructions carefully you should get something that looks like:
https://swashbucklenetcore.azurewebsites.net/swagger/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But nowhere on the page does it say that how does my `MyApi.xml` should look like?

Comment: @WorkBee You really don't need to see how the XML should look like... that is automatically generated by VisualStudio from your annotations and swachbuckle knows how to read it... also the name `MyApi.xml` is just an example, you can name yours whatever you want, just need to keep it the same across your solution

Comment: This is a really good description on how to work with Descriptions in Swagger and as @HelderSepulveda says the setting you do in step 1 is the one where you generate that XML file. You can also put any name there but make sure you use the same name in step 2 (described as MyApi.xml)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for the whole afternoon. To get my XML comments displays on Swagger UI query string's description, I checked the `XML documentation file` setting in project properties and added `IncludeXmlComments(filepath)`. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to build (through properties) and reference `c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);` the xml document in case you defined your models in another project / library

Comment: In .net core, the setting name is 'Documentation File'.  Thanks, very helpful.

Comment: Add `<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` in your `csproj` file. 

The generated `xml` file will be in your `bin` folder.

Answer (score 60):

For ASP.Net Core projects:

1. install nuget package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations
2. Use SwaggerOperation attribute for a methods like `[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Write your summary here")]`
3. Enable annotations in Startup method ConfigureServices like the following:

   ```
   services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
   {
       c.EnableAnnotations();
       c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
   });
   ```
4. To exclude public method from appearing in swagger ui use attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`. It is useful cause these methods can break swagger for some reason.

Launch project, go to localhost:[port number]/swagger and enjoy.

Comment: tnx for your solution
also my code has conflict with two using and it work with :
[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations.SwaggerOperation(Summary = "")]

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, this is what the OP expected to be able to do out-of-the box. This is just an additional package from the same developer as the original Swashbuckle.

Answer (score 26):

We use additional attributes to add required detail to the swagger documentation:

```
    [SwaggerOperationSummary("Add a new Pet to the store")]
    [SwaggerImplementationNotes("Adds a new pet using the properties supplied, returns a GUID reference for the pet created.")]
    [Route("pets")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        ...
    }
```

And then in you swagger config make sure to apply these filters:

```
config.EnableSwagger("swagger",
           c =>
           {
               c.OperationFilter<ApplySwaggerImplementationNotesFilterAttributes>();
               c.OperationFilter<ApplySwaggerOperationSummaryFilterAttributes>();
```

The code for the filters:

```
public class ApplySwaggerImplementationNotesFilterAttributes : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var attr = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerImplementationNotesAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (attr != null)
        {
            operation.description = attr.ImplementationNotes;
        }
    }
}

public class ApplySwaggerOperationSummaryFilterAttributes : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var attr = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerOperationSummaryAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (attr != null)
        {
            operation.summary = attr.OperationSummary;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering, why this is not an accepted answer. XML docs is not a way to go. First of all, XML docs describes everything in .NET terms. Imagine, that your REST uses, say, ABAP developer. The second - what is the reason to distribute XML docs at all? The third - what if I want localized docs?

Comment: No human is reading the XML doc itself.  Why would that concern the ABAP developer? It's not accepted because the other question answers this in a native way with less code.

Comment: I found something to do this in .net core from the following link, https://newbedev.com/how-to-add-method-description-in-swagger-ui-in-webapi-application

Comment: what is SwaggerImplementationNotesAttribute?

Answer (score 6):

For those who look for ability to expose custom *localized* controller names and action descriptions without shipping XML documents to customer and inventing yet another bunch of attrubutes:

```
    public static class SwaggerMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        private static readonly string[] DefaultSwaggerTags = new[]
        {
            Resources.SwaggerMiddlewareExtensions_DefaultSwaggerTag
        };

        public static void ConfigureSwagger(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddSwaggerGen(options =>
                {
                    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = "My API",
                        Version = "v 1.0"
                    });

                    // your custom config

                    // this will group actions by localized name set in controller's DisplayAttribute
                    options.TagActionsBy(GetSwaggerTags);
                    
                    // this will add localized description to actions set in action's DisplayAttribute
                    options.OperationFilter<DisplayOperationFilter>();
                });
        }

        private static string[] GetSwaggerTags(ApiDescription description)
        {
            var actionDescriptor = description.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

            if (actionDescriptor == null)
            {
                return DefaultSwaggerTags;
            }

            var displayAttributes = actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);

            if (displayAttributes == null || displayAttributes.Length == 0)
            {
                return new[]
                {
                    actionDescriptor.ControllerName
                };
            }

            var displayAttribute = (DisplayAttribute)displayAttributes[0];

            return new[]
            {
                displayAttribute.GetName()
            };
        }
    }
```

where `DisplayOperationFilter` is:

```
    internal class DisplayOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var actionDescriptor = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

            if (actionDescriptor == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var displayAttributes = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);

            if (displayAttributes == null || displayAttributes.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var displayAttribute = (DisplayAttribute)displayAttributes[0];

            operation.Description = displayAttribute.GetDescription();
        }
    }
```

Applicable for Swashbuckle 5.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to add this to your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\FileXMLName.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This is the outcome of doing this through project properties is Visual Studio. 
Right-click (your project) > Properties > Build > Output section > check "XML documentation file">

Answer (score 0):

You can use comment for documentation (3 slashes instead of standard 2) like:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is method summary I want displayed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="guid">guid as parameter</param>
/// <param name="page_number">Page number - defaults to 0</param>
/// <returns>List of objects returned</returns>
```

Comment: If you specify `IncludeXmlComments` in your Swagger config and enable the output in your project's properties, that is.