# C# Swagger Comments for for FromQuery request object

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Below code for generating a endpoint and documentation in swagger.

I need to add description to the name property which is a part of DataObjectResponse. But cant find a way to do it.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Get something
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An http action result</returns>
        public DataObjectResponse SomeMethod([FromQuery] DataObjectRequest core){
        }
      

        public class DataObjectRequest {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        }
```

Generally description can be added to query parameters using

```
       /// <summary>
       /// Get something
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns>An http action result</returns>
       /// <param name="name">Description for name</param>
       public DataObjectResponse SomeMethod(string Name){
       }
```

But am unable to find a way to add description for a property inside a object

Answer (score 0):

Does this help answer your question?

[How to add method description in Swagger UI in WebAPI Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883466/how-to-add-method-description-in-swagger-ui-in-webapi-application/52958904)

There are annotations you can use to define a lot of the variables that your endpoints deal with.

Comment: Nope. That page really talks about how to add comments to show up in swagger doc, That part is working for me.